# Javascript:: Loop until readyState is complete

Tags: javascript, loops, iframe, getelementbyid, appendchild

I was wondering why this simple code loops forever ?

```
var iBody=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

d=document.createElement('iframe');
d.src='http://m.puaction.com';
d.id="myiFrame";
iBody.appendChild(d);

while(document.getElementById('myiFrame').readyState!=='complete')
{
    //do nothing;
}

alert('iFrame fully loaded');
```

Basically I want to make sure that it's completely loaded and then check if it's completely visible (another while loop?)

Comment: Search for "javascript asynchronous". In general it is not possible to have a synchronous loop in JavaScript that depends on externally updated state (or even synchronous loops that take more than a few dozen tenths of seconds).

Answer (score 1):

I found the following link via Google: http://wpapi.com/check-iframes-loaded-completely-browser/

Don't know if it solves the 'Page Not Found' issue.

```
<script type="javascript">
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.src = "http://www.your_iframe.com/";
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") > -1 && !window.opera) {
  iframe.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (iframe.readyState == "complete"){
      alert("Iframe is now loaded.");
    }
  };
} else {
  iframe.onload = function(){
    alert("Iframe is now loaded.");
  };
}
</script>
```

I haven't tried it myself, so I don't know if it works. Good luck!

And in your case you need are not checking onreadystatechange,

Better way to implement that is

```
document.getElementById('myIframe').onreadystatechange = MyIframeReadyStateChanged;

function MyIframeReadyStateChanged()
{
    if(document.getElementById('myIframe').readyState == 'complete')
    {
        alert("Iframe is now loaded.");
    }
}
```

**And the tiny short and sweet jQuery code is**

```
$('#iframe').on('load', iframeLoaded);
```

For Sync Behaviour

```
function restOfTheCode(){
// Having your whole rest of the code
}
```

Now just do `restOfTheCode()` instead of `alert("IFrame is loaded")`.

Comment: Superb! BUT the problem is that I to prevent the code afterwards from been executed... so I need make sure the iFrame is fully loaded beforehand :)

Comment: Thanks bro but this is still async solution... :) I need to prevent the rest of the code from been executed (loop until iframe ready)

Comment: Why dont you just cut the code and paste it inside a function, and then call the function when iframes load.

Comment: This is still async solution bro, the idea here that I do not want to run the rest of the code until the iframe is fully loaded

Comment: Thats what I am saying. Cut your **Rest Of The Code** and **Paste It In A Function** and then When your `iFrame` loads just `call` that `function`.

Comment: I understand what you said bro, Let me be more clear here... It's not do X after iframe is loaded. I want to completely loop it (prevent the code from keep running) UNTIL iframe is ready... and not do X after iframe is ready. In your last example the code will keep executed :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70971/discussion-between-void-and-davidmarko).

Comment: I guess you should mark it as a correct answer, As it can solve other's problems. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use addEventListener function

```
iframe.addEventListener("readystatechange", () => {
    if (iframe.readyState == "complete") {
        alert("Iframe is now loaded.");
    }
});
```